# .NET Core MVC - Different Controllers, Different HTML In Same View-page, Different Scripts

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing an application using **.NET Core MVC**. I have different data-sets that loads through request to the controllers. For example, I have this controller methods:

- localhost/Election
- localhost/Election/2008
- localhost/Election/2008/United_States

And the methods that works for this parameters are in **ElectionController** like:

```
public async Task<IActionResults> Index(){ 

   // Return a list of data
}


public async Task<IActionResults> Index(string year){ 

   // Return a list of data
}


public async Task<IActionResults> Index(string year, string location){ 

   // Return a list of data
}
```

What happens is, these methods return some data in the same view page **/ Election/ Index**.

But I want to use different **JavaScript codes** and **different html** to represent this data-sets in the /Election/Index view page. Let's consider a **scenario**:

- If user enters : **localhost/Election** Then application is Rendering some **table** and using **/script/jsCode1.js**
- When user enters into: **localhost/Election/2008** Then application is Rendering some **cards** and using **/script/jsCode2.js**
- When user enters into: **localhost/Election/2008/United_States**
  Then application is Rendering some **charts** and using **/script/jsCode3.js**

How should I approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to render then in different pages.You should not render all in one.

Ex: **localhost/Election** will render Table.Html with their respective js. You can return specific html for specific endpoint.

Then you will have uno html for one of your endpoints in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so... first of all, there are a few different ways to deal with your issue, and each will teach you something very important about the framework.  The first two I'll mention are *not suggested* but you *should* know what is possible to do, in general, even though in this *specific* scenario they are.... bad, conceptually (imo)

So, first of all:  You can add a property to the Model.  Say, `HasYear`... and `HasCountry`.  And in your view do a `switch` or an `if` and output the needed scripts and/or html.

Second:  You can have each of the Controller endpoints use a *different view*.  So, instead of `return View()` at the end, you `return View('IndexWithElection`)`and`return View('IndexWithCountry')`

And here's the actually correct way to deal with this, conceptually:

The other two endpoints you have called `Index` *are not `Index` endpoints*.  One is `Year` and the other is `Country`.  You can annotate those endpoints with, say, `[Route("{year}")]` and `[Route("{year}/{location}")]`.  So now you have three different controller actions, with explicit routes, and explicit View cshtmls.

Good luck!